# Passing variables extracted from shell in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to pass variables extracted in a stage in Jenkinsfile between stages. For example:

```
   stage('Dummy Stage') {
    sh '''#!/bin/bash -l
        export abc=`output of some command`
        .....
        .....
       '''
```

Now, how can I pass the variable abc to a subsequent stage? I have tried setting the variable by adding a def section at the top of the file but looks like it doesnt work. In the absence of a neater way, I am having to retype the commands

Comment: Maybe [`withEnv`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables) step? I think answers to this will be opinion based.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is what I do to get the number of commits on master as a global environment variable:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    environment {
        COMMITS_ON_MASTER = sh(script: "git rev-list HEAD --count", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }

    stages {

        stage("Print commits") {
            steps {
                echo "There are ${env.COMMITS_ON_MASTER} commits on master"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seem to work only if you have one echo statement. What if we are executing multiple shell commands in the shell within the Jenkinsfile?

sh '''
      a='hello'
      b='hi'
      echo "${a}"
      echo "${a}"
'''

Here what do I do to add the value of "a" to environment variable?

Comment: def BODY = sh(script: "cat /tmp/output.text", returnStdout: true) .........getting error ......org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String BODY

Comment: You can either use a ‘script‘ to ‘def‘ine a variable only valid within that blick, or (as in my example) define a global environment variable in the ‘environment‘ block.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the longer form of the sh step and return the output (see [Pipeline document](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#setting-environment-variables-dynamically)). Your variable should be defined outside the stages.

Comment: An example of this answer: `gitShortRef = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse --short HEAD").trim()`. Never forget to `.trim()` otherwise you may end up with a new line and you'll spend hours figuring out why a == b doesnt work :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an imperatively created environment variable inside a script block in you stage steps, for example:

```
stage("Stage 1") {
    steps {
        script {
            env.RESULT_ON_STAGE_1 = sh (
                script: 'echo "Output of some command"',
                returnStdout: true
            )
        }
        echo "In stage 1: ${env.RESULT_ON_STAGE_1}"
    }
}
stage("Stage 2") {
    steps {
        echo "In stage 2: ${env.RESULT_ON_STAGE_1}"
    }
}
```

[This guide](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/) explains use of environment variables in pipelines with examples.

Answer (score 1):

My issue concerned having two 'sh' commands where one uses single quotes (where I set a variable) and the other uses double quotes (where I access 'env' variables set in the jenkinsfile such as BUILD_ID).

Here's how I solved it.

```
script {
    env.TEST = sh(
        script:
        '''
           echo "TEST"
        ''',
        returnStdout: true
    )
    sh """
         echo ${env.BUILD_ID}
         echo ${env.TEST}
    """
}
```